# Sending image/png over http protocol

Tags: java, http

I'm currently coding a Java Web Server. So far, it works to send htmt, css ... files but sending images does not work. After some research i found that you need to send the images binary data. The code for that http response:

```
response = "HTTP/1.1 200 \r\n";
        response += "Server: Java Web Server/1.0 \r\n";
        response += "Content-Type: image/png \r\n";
        response += "Connection: close \r\n";
        response += "Content-Length: " + f.length() + " \r\n";
        response += "\r\n";

        response += getBinaryCode(f);
```

getBinaryCode method:

```
private static String getBinaryCode(File f) {
    BufferedImage image;
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(f);
        ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", b);
        byte[] jpgByteArray = b.toByteArray();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte by : jpgByteArray)
            sb.append(Integer.toBinaryString(by & 0xFF));

        return sb.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "";
}
```

The problem is that the image is not displayed in
the browser. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are reading the image, but you need to then to input it in the <img> tag, perhaps as a src.

Comment: You mean like this: <img src="image.png">

Comment: But no that's not the problem. The problem is that the image isn't displayed in the browser but you can see the alt text. Anyone else ideas?

Comment: Have you read [what Integer.toBinaryString actually does](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString-int-)?  That is not the format in which an HTTP server returns an image.

Comment: Usually it converts to binary data. I have debugged the response and there was a binary code. But can you telll me how to get the format a HTTP server returns?

Comment: The word “binary” can mean raw bytes or it can mean base 2;  you have misinterpreted Integer.toBinaryString as doing the former rather than the latter.  The correct approach would be to return the raw bytes of the file;  no reason to use ImageIO at all.  However, you cannot place bytes in a String (like your `response` variable).  There is no workaround that will let you do it.  The `String(byte[])` constructor *will not* do that;  it will [decode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html) the bytes, which will alter and essentially destroy your byte data.

Comment: So I need to write the bytes to the outputstream? And how do I get the bytes from a file?